# Adding Subtitles to Audio in React

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

I am trying to add subtitles to a tutorial for my app, which I am writing in React.

I have been trying to use setTimeout as you can see below. And it runs at the beginning as it should.

```
const [paragraphs] = useState(IntroContent.intro.paragraphs);
const [displayParagraph, setDisplayParagraph] = useState("");
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

const timeoutDelays = [0, 5000, 4000, 5000, 5000, 11000, 10000, 7000, 0];

const changeParagraph = () => {
  setDisplayParagraph(paragraphs[index]);
  setIndex(index + 1);
}

setTimeout(changeParagraph, timeoutDelays[index]);
```

The captions scroll along at a close enough timing, but when it gets to the third caption, they start going to the previous caption, then changing to the correct caption after the interval again, then continues to do that until the end.

I've tried clearTimeout and it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have called setState 2 times(`setDisplayParagraph` and `setIndex`) mean with each index, it will re-render 2 times, also call setTimeout 2 times. You should call function setTimeout after component rendered by using `useEffect` and it should be only called when `index` changed:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(changeParagraph, timeoutDelays[index]);
}, [index])
```

Comment: This helped, and fixed the issue I was having. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: You're welcome.Let vote up for me if you have understood my explanation.